# Ignoring "Inactive" Entries from Every Search Method

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using a legacy database in a read only fashion. I have a user domain that includes a flag if the user is active or not. Is there a way when calling search methods like findAll to always ignore inactive users without removing them from the database or specifically in every search query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Either add a [Hibernate Filter](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) which is your most transparent option, or to add a named query like

```
static namedQueries = {
    active {
        ne 'inactive', true
    }
}
```

which will allow you to do

```
User.active.findAllBy...()
```

Comment: This was great. Hibernate filter was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.